# Can the floating point rounding mode be set at compile time in Rust?

Tags: floating-point, rust, rounding

I want to play with interval arithmetic in Rust, and to do so I need to set the rounding mode upward or downward. As I understand from some searching, setting the rounding mode will affect the performance, so I'd want to set it at compile time.

Comment: if you know how, share your knowledge with us please.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding.html might help.  It probably will apply to gcc's implementation of C and C++.  No clue about Rust or how Clang implements C/C++.  Note the comments at the very end, as well as comments under "round to nearest".

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121957/how-do-i-specify-the-rounding-mode-for-floating-point-numbers

Comment: Relevant: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/request-for-some-numerics-related-features/3530/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not reliably, no. The problem is that the LLVM backend doesn't provide any support for modifying the rounding mode, though recently there have been [some proposals to fix this](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-February/094869.html), it's not likely to be resolved in the near future.

You might be able to call out to the C `fesetround` function (in `fenv.h`) at the start of your program, but the problem is that certain optimisations (such as constant folding) would have already been performed using the default rounding mode.

Comment: ok. I see, maybe if I can desible such optimisation and change rounding using some inline assembly I can get the bahavior that I want.

Comment: I would call `fesetround` rather than use assembly: on x86 there are actually 2 different registers you need to change: the MXCSR for SSE operations, and FPSCR for x87 operations.

Comment: Yes, I have to change the two registers, but now I am facing another problem which I address in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789681/which-llvm-passes-are-responsible-for-floating-point-optimizations)