# Setting a non-default rounding mode with Rust inline asm isn't respected by the LLVM optimizer?

Tags: rust, floating-point, rounding, inline-assembly, llvm-codegen

I am working on a Rust crate which changes the rounding mode (+inf, -inf, nearest, or truncate).

The functions that change the rounding mode are written using inline assembly:

```
fn upward() {
    let cw: u32 = 0;
    unsafe {
    asm!("stmxcsr $0;
          mov $0, %eax;
          or $$0x4000, %eax;
          mov %eax, $0;
          ldmxcsr $0;"
          : "=*m"(&cw)
          : "*m"(&cw)
          : "{eax}"
        );
    }
}
```

When I compile the code in debug mode it works as intended, I get 0.3333333333337 for one-third when rounding toward positive infinity, but when I compile in release mode I get the same result no matter what rounding mode I set. I guess this behavior is due to the optimizations that the LLVM backend does.

If I knew which LLVM passes are responsible for this optimization, I can disable them as I don't see any other workaround at the moment.

Comment: I am afraid that this information may very much depends on the version of LLVM (which is free to add/remove passes), and as a result tied to the version of `rustc`. Which version of `rustc` are you using? Do you mind if this breaks when upgrading?

Comment: I am using Rust 1.10 nightly. I don't mind if it breaks. If I understand what is causing this behavior I can with a little bit of hard work make some workaround.

Comment: After some reading i think that there is some scheduling passes that are moving the divide instruction before the upward() function call. (just a guess), correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please include the exact code you're testing with: if by "one third" you mean literally the expression `1.0/3.0`, then this will be evaluated *at compile time* (i.e. using whatever rounding mode LLVM chooses to use at compile time) when optimisations are on. The question becomes harder to answer if you are computing "one third" in a way the optimiser can't see through (e.g. parsing command line arguments).

Comment: @huon This is the [code](http://pastebin.com/p4EVk6wV) that I am using to test.
Can I force llvm to use some rounding mode at compile time ??.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you can't do this.  LLVM assumes that all floating point operations use the default rounding mode, and that the floating-point control register is never read or modified.

There's been [some discussion of this issue recently on the LLVM-dev mailing list](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2016-February/094869.html), if you're interested.

In the meantime, the only reliable workaround is to use inline assembly, like  `asm!("addsd $0, $1"`.

Rust's standard library also assumes that you don't modify the rounding mode (in particular, the code for converting between floating-point and strings is sensitive to this).

Comment: If I understand you right, when using the inline assembly the rounding mode set at the mxcsr or the fctrl registers is taken into account by the computation in the asm! macro?

Comment: Yes.  At that point, you're basically just writing raw assembly, so the semantics of Rust or LLVM IR doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes ofc, LLVM optimization are made on the IR, thank you.